# TableViewRow in android on Titanium project

Tags: android, ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have created a TableView and then e created in a for as many TableViewRow as I need. The TableViewRow is created as folow:

```
var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
    selectBackgoundColor : 'transparent',
    height : '35%'
});
```

When I run my code in IOS it works perfect but in Android I need do change "height : '35%'" to a value that is not in % like "height : 121".

Why does "height : '35%'" not work in Android?

Comment: Please remove your second question from this question and ask a separate question :)

Answer (score 4):

Height `35%` doesn't work on Android, because Android doesn't know what to use for the `100%`. There are a couple of solutions you could use.

1. Calculate the 35%, based on the parent you know the height of, or of the device height. You can calculate this properly using this.

From the deviceHeight you can easily calculate 35%

```
var deviceHeight = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight;

if (OS_ANDROID){
    deviceHeight = Math.round(Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight/Ti.Platform.displayCaps.logicalDensityFactor);
}

var thirtyFive = deviceHeight * 0.35;
```

2. Use an actual fixed height. Much easier, and much more consistend across apps.

Comment: Still, I can't think of a reason why Android couldn't take the parent height like iOS does. This might make a great feature request. Please check if it has already been requested at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it has not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide a complete description in the ticket. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.